# How to do, When the video clips of YouTube are finished, show the beginning clip like in begin?

Tags: jquery, html, video, youtube, youtube-api

When the video clips of YouTube are finished, there is a mosaic of non-related YouTube clips (like similar other videos to watch).

What are our options to eliminate that please?

In other words, when the video clip is finished, we just have the first frame of our own clip again (as is the case in the beginning before clicking the clip)?

```
<div class="video">
  <iframe width="375" height="255" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_hWryogdpPI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

> rel (supported players: AS3, AS2, HTML5)
>       Values: 0 or 1. Default is 1. This parameter indicates whether the player should show related videos when playback of the initial video ends.

So your code must be:

```
<div class="video">
<iframe width="375" height="255" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_hWryogdpPI?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```